# Openswan High Availability

Tags: vpn, high-availability

I have configured hardware(juniper) to software VPN(openswan) tunnel. I want to make openswan  highly available.

I was wondering if i can configure openswan cluster, but I didn't find anything substantial regarding that. How should i make my openswan highly available so that if one node goes down, the second node would be available.

Comment: This is a forum for programmers, not system administrators, I suggest you ask your question in SuperUser.com

Comment: Thanks nrathaus. i did that.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the left/rightupdown script to re-up the 2nd connection.

Add a line in the connection's conf file like:

```
leftupdown=/etc/ipsec.d/conn7up.sh
```

Write the bash script to re-up the other connection.

I havent tested it for a while, but it can be made to work.

Note: You need to enable DPD so that the connection would detect its state.

Thanks